# How to get the ID from itunes url?

Tags: php, itunes

I need to get the item ID from the iTunes url and it used to work like this before itunes changed there url structure;

```
$musicid = 'https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-endless-bridge-single/id1146508518?uo=1&amp;v0=9989';
$musicid=explode('/id',$musicid);
$musicid=explode('?',$musicid[1]);
echo $musicid[0];
```

But now iTunes has deleted the 'id' prefix in the url so the above code does not return the id anymore, does anyone know a solution?

old itunes url; https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-endless-bridge-single/id1146508518?uo=1&v0=9989

new itunes url; https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-endless-bridge-single/1146508518?uo=1&v0=9989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just explode on the fourth slash, grabbing the fifth segment.

Simply remove `id` from `/id` (so that you `explode()` on `/`), and check the sixth index instead of the second (with `[5]` instead of `[1]`):

```
<?php

$musicid = 'https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-endless-bridge-single/1146508518?uo=1&v0=9989';
$musicid = explode('/', $musicid);
$musicid = explode('?', $musicid[5]);
echo $musicid[0]; // 1146508518
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/IqlfX)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/album/the-endless-bridge-single/1146508518?uo=1&v0=9989';

preg_match('/album\/[^\/]+\/(\d+)\?/', $url, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/tF9pS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can simply use a combination of `parse_url` and `basename`,  eg

```
$musicid = basename(parse_url($musicid, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/895029